# Pass variable in tag file JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tagfile

I want to pass a variable in tag file. My code here:

layout.tag

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@tag description="My layout" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@attribute name="title" type="java.lang.String" required="true" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My site | <c:out value="${title}" /></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="mySite" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<mySite:layout title="home">
</mySite:layout>`
```

But `<c:out value="${title} />"` always return `${title}`. I tried with `${title}` and got the same result. I dont know why...

Comment: It works for me. What container are you using and what version is it at?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm using maven and Java 1.7. I use `<%= title %>` and it works...

Comment: What Servlet container are you using? Tomcat? What version of it?

Comment: I'm using Tomcat v7.0

Comment: Check that your installation contains the EL libraries.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis How can I check it? I'm newbie in Java

Comment: check in target folder or war file in WEB-INF/lib if you have el jar library

Comment: I saw el-api-2.2.jar in Maven Dependencies. But it still doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

1.)add `<%@ attribute name="greeting" required="true" %>` in .tag file, change the name as per you convinence 

2.)    `<tag:mytag greeting="Satish">`  pass the values like this